# Typescript: interface that extends a JSON type

Tags: json, typescript, casting

I am using a generic JSON type in typescript, suggested from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897)

```js
type JSONValue = 
 | string
 | number
 | boolean
 | null
 | JSONValue[]
 | {[key: string]: JSONValue}
```

I want to be able to cast from interface types that match JSON to and from the JSON type. For example:

```js
interface Foo {
  name: 'FOO',
  fooProp: string
}

interface Bar {
  name: 'BAR',
  barProp: number;
}

const genericCall = (data: {[key: string]: JSONValue}): Foo | Bar | null => {
  if ('name' in data && data['name'] === 'FOO')
    return data as Foo;
  else if ('name' in data && data['name'] === 'BAR')
    return data as Bar;
  return null;
}
```

This currently fails because Typescript does not see how the interface could be of the same type as JSONValue:

```
Conversion of type '{ [key: string]: JSONValue; }' to type 'Foo' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: JSONValue; }' but required in type 'Foo'.
```

but analytically we of course know this is ok, because we recognize that at runtime types Foo and Bar *are* JSON compatible. How do I tell typescript that this is an ok cast?

ETA: I can follow the error message and cast to unknown first, but I'd rather not do that -- it would be better if TS actually understood the difference, and I'm wondering if it's possible at all.

Comment: Have you tried to pass it to `unknown` and then to `Foo` or `Bar` 
`(data as unknown) as Foo`

Comment: rewrite `data as Foo` to `data as unknown as Foo`

Comment: yes I could just follow the TS error warning, but I'd rather not do that -- it would be better if TS actually understood the comparison, and I want to know if thats even possible

Comment: I don't think that's possible, maybe you should try to create a `toFoo` or `toBar` method or maybe something like `{...data} as Foo` (I'm not sure of this one)...

Comment: not a bad idea! though this does incur an additional copy cost for something that should be a 'free' typecast, and I think this doesn't work so well in the other direction

Comment: TypeScript doesn't narrow automatically by checking non-union types like `JSONValue` for having properties or what those properties contain; see [ms/TS#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732).  You could write a user-defined type guard function to let the compiler know that's what you're doing with the check, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQ8P7W) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the response @jcalz. One thing I don't follow in the playground link: how does the `hasKeyVal` function know about interfaces Foo and Bar? They don't get passed in implicitly or explicitly, so is the `genericCall` function doing some kind of narrowing there?

Comment: When `hasKeyVal(data, "name", "FOO")` returns `true`, then `data` gets narrowed from `{[k: string]: JSONValue}` to {name: "FOO"}` which is [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) identical to `Foo` so it compiles.  Does that makes sense?  Should I write up an answer explaining this or is there some outstanding issue that you would still need addressed?

Comment: ah understood. This definitely answers the minimum reproducible example above, but in practice Foo and Bar are placeholders for more complex interfaces. If I add another field to Foo, the playground link above no longer works. Edited the question to reflect this

Comment: Have you considered having your interfaces extend `Record<string, JSONValue>`?

Comment: Can you edit your [mre] to reflect the new requirements also?  It should at least work to do a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N91dJN), right?  I mean, you're not actually checking that `data` is a `Foo` then, just if it has the right `name` property, so we can't expect the compiler to verify that it is a `Foo`.  You can assert or you can really test.  Which one did you want to do for this question?

Comment: O neat, yea the type assertion is fine. Didn't realize that we can just cast using `as` at that point. If you submit that as an answer, happy to approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the compiler does not use the check `if ('name' in data && data['name'] === 'FOO')` to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `data` from its original type of `{[key: string]: JSONValue}`.  The type `{[key: string]: JSONValue}` is not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and currently [`in` operator checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) only narrow values of union types.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) to do such narrowing, but for now it's not part of the language.

That means `data` stays of type `{[key: string]: JSONValue}` after the check. When you then try to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `data` is of type `Foo` via `data as Foo`, the compiler warns you that you might be making a mistake, because it doesn't see `Foo` and `{[key: string]: JSONValue}` are types that are related enough.

If you are sure that what you're doing is a good check, you could always do with the compiler suggests and type-assert to an intermediate type which is related to both `Foo` and `{[key: string]: JSONValue}`, such as `unknown`:

```
return data as unknown as Foo; // okay
```

If that concerns you then you can write your own [user defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which performs the sort of narrowing you expect from `if ('name' in data && data['name'] === 'FOO')`.  Essentially if that check passes, then we know that `data` is of type `{name: 'FOO'}`, which is related enough to `Foo` for a type assertion.  Here's a possible type guard function:

```
function hasKeyVal<K extends PropertyKey, V extends string | number |
  boolean | null | undefined | bigint>(
    obj: any, k: K, v: V): obj is { [P in K]: V } {
  return obj && obj[k] === v;
}
```

So instead of `if ('name' in data && data['name'] === 'FOO')`, you write `if (hasKeyVal(data, 'name', 'FOO'))`.  The return type `obj is {[P in K]: V}` means that if the function returns `true`, the compiler should narrow the type of `obj` to something with a property whose key is of type `K` and whose value is of type `V`.  Let's test it:

```
const genericCall = (data: { [key: string]: JSONValue }): Foo | Bar | null => {
  if (hasKeyVal(data, 'name', 'FOO'))
    return data as Foo; // okay, data is now {name: 'FOO'} which is related to Foo
  else if (hasKeyVal(data, 'name', 'BAR'))
    return data as Bar;  // okay, data is now {name: 'BAR'} which is related to Bar
  return null;
}
```

Now it works.  The `hasKeyVal()` check narrows `data` to something with a `name` property of the right type, and this is related enough to `Foo` or `Bar` for the type assertion to succeed (the type assertion is still necessary because a value of type `{name: 'Foo'}` might not be a `Foo` if `Foo` has other properties).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHIDUCGAbArtAvAKCigB8oBnYAJwEsA7Ac0JKlqwFsAjCSp0jge34YIaWrxZYMGcfGTpsEANoBdcQG8oigNYQQALnJU69ZQdmpMOKAF98dusG4AzNAGNoAMUFQ1TWmjYIAwByDwQEYIAaJidBAAVKfjADChoGfFt8B2c3aAAhNEofPwCgqGC8gEEAJSimDkKEpINWTm4Abgz8JyxaV2BqflooAAs0MgBpXXkAHgmoCAAPR1oAEzIoJshKUCmQSKgUBeWINY3U42ZWriLiesFhUSvJDGZe1YgnOghV5g5qegOAB8AAomER+BwAFYGUT7KBaAwTA4ANwMKAAlAZIVCoNQNhpFHE8cMJqZDjZikRKBBgFhKMMcVAAGTMqA47TKKC4HlQFGdTKuIYUKD0U7caiuADCmFeuCgINWaGAaAMhJ0+kMaRMZkQFgUNixUC8-GYBVuEik3KBVLxTgVY0m00wiuVaAOwX8gSi5TCEQxGPBUBpdIZUCVKqg42NgnaUAA9PH2Vo0PCI2g8RtaPwAO4+L1lULhYLWKA5kaSkaZ4MQDDKn5QYCmk1MWtkaDUe0gx17eSulUegs+io1YIBoMh+nDdNRjbmuMJpP8FNpt3V7N5tQFkJVWql8uV6s0uuOX5NqDmpiTsOsKQCuxAA)