# Typescript: passing interface as parameter for a function that expects a JSON type

Tags: json, typescript, types, casting

This is an extension of [Typescript: interface that extends a JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73280790/typescript-interface-that-extends-a-json-type)

Given a JSON type like:

```
type JSONValue = 
 | string
 | number
 | boolean
 | null
 | JSONValue[]
 | {[key: string]: JSONValue}
```

I'd like to find a way to tell typescript that interfaces that match the JSONType should be auto-casted when passed into functions that accept the JSONType. For example:

```
interface Foo {
  name: 'FOO',
  fooProp: string
}

const bar = (foo: Foo) => { return foo }

const wrap = (fn: (...args: JSONValue[]) => JSONValue, args: JSONValue[]) => {
  return fn(...args);
}

wrap(bar, {name: 'FOO', fooProp: 'hello'});
```

This currently fails with:

```
Argument of type '(foo: Foo) => Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: JSONValue[]) => JSONValue'.
  Types of parameters 'foo' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'JSONValue' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
```

even though analytically we know that the passed in foo is a JSON compatible type.

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHIDUCGAbArtAvAKCigB8oBnYAJwEsA7Ac0JKlqwFsAjCSp0jge34YIaWrxZYMGcfGTpsEANoBdcQG8oigNYQQALnJU69ZQdmpMOKAF98dusG4AzNAGNoAMUFQ1TWmjYIAwByDwQEYIAaJidBAAVKfjADChoGfFt8V35aCigONEooXCgAClj+Ay9+AEpigD4fKEoIYCxKWigKmzts3OAoAHdKNDBisqdaA1KAOjnC+jIzRAsFFTrcRvN5HEioBaXYFZ2lZQ3G3yIWto6u2ln5ykWagG4Mu2HR0oLKPbV-QIhMIRPYVBJJEIACwgUn4wWsryAA)

Is there a way to get typescript to recognize that this interface is in fact also JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues within your implementation currently. You are trying to type the function `wrap` as if it accepts a function `fn` which may have arbitrary `JSONValue[]` data passed into it. But then you are passing in `bar`, a function which *only* accepts `Foo`. To fix this, we can make `wrap` generic over `T` where `T` represents the parameters of `fn`. We would then type `args` to be of type `T` too, so that we can pass `args` to `fn` safely.

Notice how I made `args` a *spread parameter* which it was not before. We don't want `args` to be a tuple type, as you don't pass a tuple to the function when calling it.

```
const wrap = <T extends JSONValue[]>(
  fn: (...args: T) => JSONValue, 
  ...args: T
) => {
  return fn(...args);
}
```

---

But this will still not work. `Foo` is currently an `interface` which don't have implicit index signatures (see [#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)). An `interface` can not fulfill the `{[key: string]: JSONValue}` constraint due to this missing implicit index signature. The only workaround we have without widening the `JSONValue` type is to convert `Foo` to be a `type`.

```
type Foo = {
  name: 'FOO',
  fooProp: string
}

const bar = (foo: Foo) => { return foo }

const wrap = <T extends JSONValue[]>(
  fn: (...args: T) => JSONValue, 
  ...args: T
) => {
  return fn(...args);
}

wrap(bar, { name: 'FOO', fooProp: 'hello'});
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHIDUCGAbArtAvAKCigB8oBnYAJwEsA7Ac0JKlqwFsAjCSp0jge34YIaWrxZYMGcfGTpsEANoBdcQG8oigNYQQALnJU69ZQdmpMOKAF98d0JCgAxQVFxQ1TWmjYQDAcicEBH8AGiYAM0EABUp+MAMKGgZ8W3wAY35aCigONEo3KAAKKP4DF34ASjcAPg8oSghgLEpaKFKbO0zs4CgAd0o0MEKAHgAVKAgAD2AIWgATMlhECwUVGqLI2gMigDp9-PoyAzHq3DrzeRxQqCZ93cPjqDH8M7rPIkbm1vbaPYPKEdKgBuVJ2AZDIp5Sg3DTeXwBIIhG6lWLxAIACwgUn4-msIKAA)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tobias, that was super clearly reasoned and very helpful. You mention widening the JSON type -- what would that look like? I'm inheriting a legacy codebase and it would be hard to map all the relevant interfaces to this json type