# Argument of type 'FooBar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSONObject'. Index signature is missing in type 'FooBar'

Tags: javascript, typescript

My goal is to create a type called `JSONObject` for any JSON like object. The best I found so far is:

```
interface JSONObject {
    [x: string]: JSONValue;
}

interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> { }
type JSONValue =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | JSONObject
    | JSONArray;
```

To be used in low level function like this:

`function saveJson(data: JSONObject) { ... }`

Which works for most cases but this case, it does not work

```
export interface FooBar {
    foo: number,
    bar: number,
}
const data: FooBar = await fetchSomething();
saveJson(data);
```

With the compile time error:

> Argument of type 'FooBar' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'JSONObject'.   Index signature is missing in type 'FooBar'.

My goal to remove the error without touching `FooBar`

Comment: what's the signature for `fetchSomething`?

Comment: Promise of `FooBar` so `data` is `FooBar`

Comment: The problem is that you're using interfaces (which can be extended) instead of type aliases (which can't). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74695404/438273) and this playground: https://tsplay.dev/wE49yW